# how to find how many items need to sum to get given sum in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array

```
var array = [4,2,6,8,1,6,5,2];
var samNeeded = 20;
```

as above i need to get how many items need to sum from start of the array to get sum needed

example needed output

```
var output = [4,2,6,8]
```

as first four items need to sum up to get the total 20

Comment: What if the sum cannot be achieved?

Comment: What if the sum is 19? Or 22? What should you do?

Comment: no issue @iota always start from array will have the total

Comment: Do you need the sum of the output array elements to be exactly equal to sumNeeded?

Comment: i need count from index 0 of source array @Platus

Comment: Please show your own attempt at solving this problem so we can help you debug where you went wrong.

Comment: @KATJSrinath I count from index 0 of source array in my answer ;)

Comment: @Platus it gived last element as per the answer give next element i.e 1

Comment: @KATJSrinath check my edited answer, I fixed that

Comment: @KATJSrinath can you accept the answer if it's ok for you?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the best approach, but it works for your example:

```js
const array = [4,2,6,8,1,6,5,2];
const samNeeded = 20;

let sum = 0;
const result = [];

// as long as array still has items and we haven't reached the target sum…
while (array.length && sum < samNeeded) {
  result.push(array.shift()); // consume the next item of the input array
  sum += result[result.length - 1]; // add it to sum as we go.
}

// it's not clear from your question whether you need the number of items…
console.log(result.length);

// or the items themselves:
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You're actualy adding the last element value to the sum, it should be the first element

Comment: The next value is being pushed to result, making it the _last_ element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```js
const array = [4, 2, 6, 8, 1, 6, 5, 2];
const sumNeeded = 20;

let auxSum = 0;
const res = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (auxSum >= sumNeeded) break;
  auxSum += array[i];
  res.push(array[i]);
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Don't know why you wrapped it in a function. The `for` loop is the simplest more direct solution. The function clouds up the simplicity of what the OP asked for. (and it will confuse readers about your intent).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array#reduce`.

```js
var array = [4,2,6,8,1,6,5,2];
var sumNeeded = 20;
let [res] = array.reduce(([res, sum],curr)=>
    [res.concat(sum >= sumNeeded ? []: curr), sum + (sum >= sumNeeded ? 0: curr)],
    [[], 0]);
console.log(res);
```